# AJAX POST Won't Work With document.getElementById Variables

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have an html form and ajax call that store data in MySQL via a PHP page.

The code for all three is copied below.  (Please note the //)

All three work fine as long as I have the variables hard coded in the function where the ajax call stores them.  However, when I comment out the hard coded variables and run it with the regular variables, it does not work.

JavaScript AJAX Call
    $("#buttonSubmit").click(function() {

```
//var questionID       = obj.Questions[i].questionID;
//var shortAnswerValue = document.getElementById('txtShortAnswerValue').value;      
//var longAnswerText   = document.getElementById('txtLongAnswerText').value;

var questionID      = "SampleQID";
var shortAnswerValue    = "Sample Short";       
var longAnswerText      = "Sample Long";

$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "SaveUpdatesTemplate.php",
     data: "questionID=" + questionID + "&shortAnswerValue=" + shortAnswerValue + "&longAnswerText=" + longAnswerText, 
}); // end ajax function
     document.getElementById("txtLongAnswerText").reset();  
});  // end button submit function
```

Associated HTML
    Select Inspection or Project Phase
    
     Select Inspection or Project Phase

```
<label for="selectSection">Select Inspection or Project Phase</label>
<select class="form-control" id="selectSection" name="selectSection">
    <option> Select Inspection or Project Phase</option>
</select>   

<button type="button" class="form-control" id="buttonStart" name="buttonStart" value="List Questions">Start - Click to Populate Question List</button>
<label for="selectQuestion">Select Task or Question to Update</label>
<select class="form-control" id="selectQuestion" name="selectQuestion" >
<option> Select Task or Question to Update </option>
</select>   

<!-- short answer below -->
<label for="txtShortAnswerValue">Short Answer</label>
<select  class="form-control" id="txtShortAnswerValue" name="txtShortAnswerValue">
<option value="1" selected>worst</option>
<option value="3">middle</option>
<option value="5">best</option>
</select>

<!-- long answer below -->
<label for="txtLongAnswerText">Long Answer / Notes</label>
<textarea class="form-control" name="txtLongAnswerText" id="txtLongAnswerText" rows=3>
</textarea>
```

Associated PHP Code
    // Assign PHP variables to POST results from client

```
$questionID         = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['questionID']));
$shortAnswerValue       = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['shortAnswerValue']));
$longAnswerText         = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['longAnswerText']));

   //SQL STATEMENT 
   $sql="INSERT INTO Updates (questionID, shortAnswerValue, longAnswerText)
   VALUES
   ('$questionID', '$shortAnswerValue', '$longAnswerText')";
```

Comment: Ugh. I just can't make myself read it all. TOO LONG.

Comment: That's a lot of information. Unfortunately not the info we need. What is exactly not working? Are the values not stored, is the query not executed, is PHP throwing an error, is JS throwing an error, .. ? BTW: in the first line what is `obj.Questions`?

Comment: If you are using jQuery, why would you use regular JavaScript as well? `document.getElementById('yourId')` is `$('#yourId')`. If you're using the Library save yourself the keystrokes.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
data: encodeURI("questionID=" + questionID + "&shortAnswerValue=" + shortAnswerValue + "&longAnswerText=" + longAnswerText);
```

The problem is the spaces in `var questionID`, and so on. Also you have an unnecessary comma before the end of the Object you passed to `$.ajax()`, right after your `data` property value.